# Codeigniter internal server error 500 on PK conflict using query builder

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

For an AJAX endpoint on Codeigniter my if-else condition is given below -

```
if ($this->db->insert('sets', $data)) {
    $arr = array('status' => 'success', 'result' => $data);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    return;
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'exception' => 'cannot insert given data to db');
    return;
}
```

It works as expected, returns the data on success and update the view accordingly.

But for db->insert() failure on PK constraint (e,g knowingly inserting values which contradicts with PK [duplicate entry]); I was never receiving my data on success. After adding the fail callback to ajax I found that the CI3 is causing 500 rather than 200.
Thus not providing the [json](/questions/tagged/json) I was expecting in the ajax callback in my view.

```
$http.get(url, {})
    .then(function successCb(data) {
        if (data.data.status == 'error') {
            $scope.addExceptionMsg = data.data.exception;
            $("#errorPopup").modal(); // show the error popup
        } else {
            glueFactory.updateSet(data.data.result);
        }
    }, function errorCb(response) {
        console.log(response); // <== I should not be here even on db insert failure.
    });
```

How can I fix this issue while still using the query builder?

Comment: Try with removing both `return;` lines from constroller.

Comment: @Tpojka Already did that with no luck, but I believe that is not the issue because if it was atleast I should have gotten the json_encode() call instead of 500.

Comment: What framework/library is that? What is `.then` method?

Comment: @Tpojka it is angularjs, I believe then method just sets up the callback functions (but I am not sure as it is provided by angularjs). BTW I know that the call to db->insert() will fail because of PK constrain.

Comment: Try with `echo json_encode($data)` to see what is intended to insert in DB (without inserting, just echo `$data` back to front end).

Comment: @Tpojka the query is ok if there is no conflict on db, it insert the data to db and updates a table on the page. But executing the same query results in PK violation and thus the query fails. In error case instead of going to my own exception block, CI3 is just giving me 500.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97716/discussion-between-tpojka-and-fadedreamz).